# Kicad - Custom library folder

Tags: kicad

How do you create a folder to hold your custom components? The tutorials I've come across such as [the official getting started guide](http://docs.kicad-pcb.org/4.0.5/en/getting_started_in_kicad.html#using-component-library-editor) show the creation of only one custom component. Using this approach you end up with several folders... For example in the image below, I have created two custom libraries, ALU_ROM and CONTROL_UNIT. Each appears in its own folder... However, I want instead to have a folder named COMPUTER, where both components (and more in the future) reside. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you actually want to create a component, and not a hierarchical sheet? Keep in mind a component has to map to a single part on the PCB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## To create a new library:

Click on the "Create New Library" button on the top left -

[image]

## To choose a library for your new symbol:

When you click the "New Symbol" button it prompts you to choose which library you want to add it to. Click on the library you want and press "OK" (or just double click).

[image]

Then just save your symbol as you normally would. It'll be added to the library.

## To move a symbol to a different library:

It's as simple as Cut & Paste.

[image]
[image]

## To export the symbol you're currently viewing into a different library:

Click the "Export" button...

[image]

... and save it to the library you want.

[image]

Comment: I was trying a much more complicated way of copying a library and pasting it and then renaming it, etc. This is a lot simpler :)

Comment: Oh wow, I think the UI for this task greatly improved when compared to KiCad 4. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I finagled a solution for KiCad 4. It is nowhere near as elegant as *@darius-fieschko*'s solution above for KiCad 5. You should do yourself a favour and upgrade your version of KiCad. With that said, here's the painful way I got it to work in KiCad 4.

- Create a new component
- Click "Save current component to new library"
- Use the name you want for the library/folder

[image: 1.png]

- Add the component to the search path
- To do this, navigate to *Preferences* > *Component Libraries*
- Add the "Component library files" (In this example, *my_library_name.lib*)
- Add the "User defined search path" (In this example, the folder containing *my_library_name.lib*)

[image: 1b.png]

- Set your library as the current working library
- To do this, click "Select working library" and choose your library

[image: 2.png]
[image: 2a.png]

- Now when you open the "Library Browser", you should see your library

[image: 3a.png]
[image: 3.png]

- Now when you create a new component, you use the "Update current component in current library" button to add it the working library
- In the example, I created a new component called *part_a*

[image: 4.png]

- When you open the "Library Browser", you should see the new component inside your library

[image: 5.png]

- I went ahead and added a few more components to the library

[image: 6.png]

- And then deleted the initial "my_library_name" component (which acted only as a placeholder to create the library)

[image: 7a.png]
[image: 7.png]

- The library now looks like this:

[image: 8.png]

- And can be saved by clicking "Save current library to disk"

[image: 9.png]